# Joined boolean optimizations Swift

Tags: swift, if-statement

Is there a better way to write this if-statement, which has ultimately four outcomes among three variables?

I looked into guard and switch but I'm not sure if either of those capture the joined boolean states well?  I could individually list the four outcomes as joined boolean statements (eg, isPartialResult == true && calculated == nil, so on..) but that isn't necessarily more readable or efficient (more to type). Thanks!

```
case .BinaryOperation(let function):
            if isPartialResult == true {
                if calculated == nil {
                    log += (" \(accumulator) \(symbol)")        // add new op
                } else {
                    log += (" \(symbol)")                       // add symbol to calculated, prepare for new op
                    calculated = nil
                }
            } else {
                if log.characters.count <= 1 {
                    log += (" \(accumulator) \(symbol)")        // start from beginning
                } else {
                    log += (" \(symbol)")                       // restart from equal
                }
            }
            executePendingBinaryOperation()
            pending = pendingBinaryOperationInfo(binaryFunction: function, firstOperand: accumulator)
            isPartialResult = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given 3 values

```
let isPartialResult = true
let calculated: String?
let log = "hello"
```

You can use a `switch` this way

```
switch (isPartialResult, calculated, log.characters.count) {
case (true, nil, _): break
case (true, let _, _): break
case (false, _, 0...1): break
case (false, _, 2...Int.max): break
default: fatalError()
}
```

Now just replace each of the 4 breaks with your outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `if let ... = ...` to unwrap the `calculated` value (ie check for nil).

```
if isPartialResult == true {
    if let _ = calculated {
        log += (" \(symbol)")
        calculated = nil
    } else {
        log += (" \(accumulator) \(symbol)")
    }
} else {
    log += log.characters.count <= 1 ? (" \(accumulator) \(symbol)") : (" \(symbol)")
}
```

or same thing, but with `guard`:

```
if isPartialResult == true {
    guard let _ = calculated else {
        log += (" \(accumulator) \(symbol)")
    }

    log += (" \(symbol)")
    calculated = nil
} else {
    log += log.characters.count <= 1 ? (" \(accumulator) \(symbol)") : (" \(symbol)")
}
```

Chose any from this two.

Comment: Thanks for the check for nil tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can burn it all down to one line without an if statement.

```
log = isPartialResult ? ((calculated == nil) ? log  +  accumulator/symbol : 3) : ((xyz.count <= 1) ? (log + 10) : 6)
```

Ask a question. I'm not sure what is the downside of using trinary operator. It just keeps my code clean

Comment: @pacification Absolutely agree.

Comment: @pacification Do you think there might be a performance issue here? I think that might be more important.